# What's the best way to use react-redux with event based 3rd party library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

What is the best way to wire up a view to a library which continually dispatches events? I saw in the redux real-world example that it's best to use mapDispatchToProps and inject your loading action. In our case we need to listen for events to dispatch over time. I thought we could use middleware to do this but I'm not 100% sure. There other alternative would be to do the listening inside the action creator itself.

Any ideas?

// app.jsx

```
<div>
  <MyCollection name="ONE" />
  <MyCollection name="TWO" />
</div>
```

// my-collection.jsx

```
import {load} from './actions';

class MyCollection extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.load(this.props.name);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.name !== this.props.name) {
      this.props.load(this.props.name);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.name}: {this.props.value}</div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    value: state.value
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  loadAndWatch
}

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyCollection);
```

// actions.js

```
import {MyCollection} from '@corp/library';

export function load(name) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    MyCollection.getValue(name, value => {
      dispatch(setValue(name));
    })
  }
}

export function setValue(name) {
  return {
    type: 'SET_VALUE',
    name
  }
}
```

// reducer.js

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_WATCHING':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {isWatching: true});
    case 'SET_VALUE':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {value: action.value});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

// middleware.js

```
import {setValue} from './actions';

function middleware({dispatch, getState}) {
  return next => action => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_VALUE':
        next(action);

        if (getState().isWatching) {
          return;
        }

        MyCollection.addChangeListener(name, value => {
          dispatch(setValue(name))
        });

        dispatch({type: 'SET_WATCHING'});    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The best way is to subscribe to events after you initialize your store, then the listener would trigger an action and the data would change.

Comment: @BlairAnderson the problem is I don't know what events to listen to at init time. It depends on what view components are used etc. There are 100s of possible events in our app.

Comment: You should subscribe inside `componentDidMount` and then unsubscribe inside `componentWillUnmount`. on subscribing to your events, you should dispatch actions to redux.  It seems like your app architecture is not designed to fit perfectly into the react/redux world because custom events are too flexible and ambiguous.

Comment: I agree with @BlairAnderson, i think you should play around more with the store and dispatch actions on event listeners than trying to listen for events on your components

Answer (score 0):

I believe [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org) is what you are looking for, in case you don't want to overcomplicate your app with home-made middlewares.